Dell R410 Server Not Recognizing SATA Drives in BIOS
My company recently purchased a Dell R410 server, and I encountered an issue where my SATA drives are not recognized by the BIOS. I entered the BIOS setup, set the SATA mode to AHCI, and disabled RAID because I don't intend to use it. The hard drives can blink, indicating power and activity.
I verified that all SATA data and power cables are securely connected and tried connecting the drives to different SATA ports on the motherboard.
Despite these efforts, the BIOS still does not recognize the SATA drives. The physical drives are listed as unknown in the BIOS when AHCI is chosen, and I receive a message indicating "AHCI BIOS not installed," suggesting that the drives are not being detected. I have double-checked the physical connections and BIOS settings multiple times to ensure everything is configured correctly.

Just to confirm - you do have your drives mounted in Dell's hot-swap carrier trays? My own experience is that unless the tray is in place and the latch closed, the disk will seem to be powered but the BIOS won't see it.
